# crontab -e on raspberry pi seems to excecute file but it does not save and open output file from script

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

As the title says, I have a simple script that I can execute without issues manually. I want it to be executed as the pi starts so I found that I can add the path to crontab -e in the following format:

```
@reboot python3 path/file.py &
```

The file it is supposed to save an image file and then show it on a screen but it is not saving the image -at least in the directory it is supposed to. What might be happening? If it is of any use, the image is fetched from the web.

Comment: There's two ways to fix it. Either modify your file.py and give it an absolute path instead of making it safe in it's working directory. Or change your crontab command to first cd to the folder you want. 

@reboot cd /to/the/folder/you/want && python3 path/file.py

Comment: I did what you suggested using cd /target/folder... but it does not work either. How would you go about making an absolute path? Is it absolute to the script or to the file the script saves and then summons into the screen?

Comment: You need to show us your file.py.

I imagine there's some part in it where it goes open('somefile.png', 'w') as img: img.write(data).

Change somefile.png to /full/path/somefile.png

Comment: Sorry, your original approach worked! there was a typo on it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.